# Exporting a table to Excel in CSV format

Tags: list-manipulation, export, csv-format

I am trying to create a table which when exported in a .csv format and opened in MS.Excel has the following form;

> ```
> i1    j1    f[i1,j1]
> i1    j2    f[i1,j2]
> i1    j3    f[i1,j3]
> i2    j1    f[i2,j1]
> i2    j2    f[i2,j2]
> i2    j3    f[i2,j3]
> i3    j1    f[i3,j1]
> i3    j2    f[i3,j2]
> i3    j3    f[i3,j3]
> ...
> ```

I have tried;

```
myTable = Table[{i, j, f[i, j]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
Export["out.csv", myTable]
```

but it comes out as;

> ```
> {{{1, 1, f[1, 1]}, {1, 2, f[1, 2]}, {1, 3, f[1, 3]}}, 
>  {{2, 1, f[2, 1]}, {2, 2, f[2, 2]}, {2, 3, f[2, 3]}}, 
>  {{3, 1, f[3, 1]}, {3, 2, f[3, 2]}, {3, 3, f[3, 3]}}}
> ```

Which in MS.Excel looks like;

> ```
> {i1    j1    f[i1,j1]}    {i1    j2    f[i1,j2]}    {i1    j3    f[i1,j3]}
> {i2    j1    f[i2,j1]}    {i2    j2    f[i2,j2]}    {i2    j3    f[i2,j3]}
> {i3    j1    f[i3,j1]}    {i3    j2    f[i3,j2]}    {i3    j3    f[i3,j3]}
> ```

The 3 sets of nested brackets means it doesn't come out how I wanted it.

I am sure this is a really simple/dumb question but I am a bit lost here.

Comment: if you have a list `list={{i1,j1},...,{in,jn}}` then this code will form the table you need `{Sequence@@#,f@@#}&/@list`

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks for that. I clearly need to take some time to learn some of the more esoteric syntax. I've just found the Flatten[] function which appears to reduce my table to 2-dimensions which get the result but probably not as elegant or efficient as yours

Comment: I think you wanted to address your comment to @k_v.

Comment: @m_goldberg your right I did, sorry; new here also:)

Comment: @k_v thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if you want numbers or functions. Since you are using comma separated variables I have converted your f[i,j] to a string to avoid the comma in the function creating an extra column.

```
myTable = Table[{i, j, ToString[f[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

If you look at the output there is a level of bracketing associated with each table index. You don't want this so we can remove it with flatten

```
flatTable = Flatten[myTable, 1]
```

Now use TableForm to check the configuration

```
TableForm[flatTable]
```

The output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can export

```
Export["out.csv", flatTable]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to post-process `myTable` to get rid of the extra nesting.

Look up [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) and [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html) for this:

```
Join @@ myTable
```

With [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Flatten.html):

```
Flatten[myTable, 1]
```

With the new-in-10 [`Catenate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Catenate.html)

```
Catenate[myTable]
```

So which one should you use?

Performance wise, they're mostly the same.  They all preserve packed arrays.  I used to use `Join @@` up to Mathematica 9 because I prefer not to have another layers of hard-to-read brackets with `Flatten[..., 1]`.  Since version 10, I use `Catenate`, e.g. `Catenate@Table[..., { }, { }]`.