# beginner's question: change a parameter while get variable answers

Tags: functions

I'm new to Mathematica from R, since R is not quite good at dealing with the following problem. Say, i want to solve the function a x - 10 = 0. Each time I change the value of a, say, from 1 to 10 by 1, I get x as output.

Take a =2, i learnt the command

```
a=2
Solve[a * x - 10 ==0, x]
```

Then i got x value. However, i have to manually change a=3, a=4, a=5... which is annoying.

I went online and found the following ways. Either

```
Manipulate[{a, Solve[a*x - 10 == 0, x]}, {a, 1, 5, 1}]
```

or

```
Solve[#*x - 10 == 0, x] & /@ Range[1, 5, 1]
```

However, the output is like

```
{{{x -> 10}}, {{x -> 5}}, {{x -> 10/3}}, {{x -> 5/2}}, {{x -> 2}}}
```

which i don't know how to save it as a csv for further use in R. I want it to look like

```
a x
1 10
2 5
3 10/3
4 5/2
5 2
```

Any suggestions? thanks in advance

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables)

Comment: See also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/57).

Comment: For the CSV export part see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77708/exporting-a-table-to-excel-in-csv-format?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

How about `Table[{a, x /. Solve[a*x - 10 == 0, x][[1, 1]]} // N, {a, 1, 10}]` ?

You can then export to `.csv` using `Export["ans.csv", %]`.

Comment: You probably want to do `Export["ans.csv", Catenate[{{{"a", "x"}}, %}]]` to give column headers as requested.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this question should eventually be closed as its elements have been addressed before.  However since you are new I hope to give a better welcome than merely "go read this" etc.  To that end:

1. If you can solve your equation Symbolically you can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) once, then populate values of a as desired.
2. The output format of `Solve` is a [`List`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/List.html) of Lists of [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) expressions.  Each sublist is a solution.  They are in this format for convenience, not to make things difficult.  See [Assign the results from a Solve to variable(s)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6669/121) for a few ideas about handling these.

As an example I will perform a symbolic `Solve`, then extract the first (only) `x` solution and name it `x1`, then use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to create your table of results.  You can [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) this or display it with [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html).

```
sol = Solve[a*x - 10 == 0, x]

x1 = x /. sol[[1]]     (* see documentation for ReplaceAll and Part *)

Table[{a, x1}, {a, 1, 10}]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 10/a}}
>
> 10/a
>
> {{1, 10}, {2, 5}, {3, 10/3}, {4, 5/2}, {5, 2}, {6, 5/3},
>  {7, 10/7}, {8, 5/4}, {9, 10/9}, {10, 1}}
> ```

To differentiate this answer from Chen Stats Yu's here is another formulation that in time may interest you:

```
fx1 = {#, x} & /. First @ Solve[#*x - 10 == 0, x]

Array[fx1, 10]
```

> ```
> {{1, 10}, {2, 5}, {3, 10/3}, {4, 5/2}, {5, 2}, {6, 5/3},
>  {7, 10/7}, {8, 5/4}, {9, 10/9}, {10, 1}}
> ```

Comment: thanks for the kind help. I would like to learn more, to burden you less :)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do it with a function :

```
solveme[a_] := Flatten[{a, Values[Solve[a*x - 10 == 0, x]]}]
```

Note that the Flatten in my answer and the [[1,1]] are both ways to remove nested {}'s.  Chen's does it by selecting `Part` mine does it by extracting the `Values` from Solve then using Flatten to remove nested lists.

Pop in a range of values for a

```
result = solveme[#] & /@ Range[1, 5, 1]

Export["result.csv", result]
```

Alternatively you can use the nice columnar formatting of `Dataset` via `Association`

```
solveme2[n_] := Association[{"a" -> n, "x" -> x /. Solve[n*x - 10 == 0, x][[1, 1]]}]
```

Dataset formats with a nice columnar layout and could support further querying.

```
result2 = solveme2[#] & /@ Range[1, 5, 1] // Dataset
```

[image: Dataset]

Then your csv export is nicely WYSIWIG with column headings in 10.1,

```
Export["result2.csv", result2]
```

for 10.0.2 and earlier providing you can work around the inability of Dataset to be exported cleanly.

```
Export["result2.csv", Catenate[{DeleteDuplicates[Keys[#]], Values[#]}]] &[Normal[result2]]
```

Basically we split the Keys and the Values of the Dataset up after converting it to an Association using Normal.  We use Slot (#) and Function (&) to create a pure function in the Export expression that lets us pass result2 in twice, once to create the column headers using Keys - which we de-duplicate, and again to create the column values using Values.  Then we merge it into a big list using Cantenate so the columns export correctly.

Comment: thanks to the useful answer! that really works fine for me, and I am really grateful.

Comment: Dear Mr. Gordon, now i have one more problem and may need your kind help. Now there are not only a, but also b

a = Range[1, 5, 1];
b = {3.4, 5.7, 6.9, 20, -1};
solveme[a_, b_] :=
 Flatten[
  {a, b,
   Values[
    NSolve[{a x - b == 0}, x]]
   }]
solvemeresult = solveme[#] & /@ {a, b}

I'm afraid the last code is wrong and i get the answer 

{solveme[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}], solveme[{3.4, 5.7, 6.9, 20, -1}]}

which is not what i want. Would you mind giving me some advice about how to correct it please?

Comment: Thanks! I find this thread that helps to my question [link]http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24939/another-way-to-do-this-mapping-of-a-two-argument-function